# Allow only one radiobutton selection in Gridview in each row in asp.net using Javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to select only one radio button from each row of grid view using JavaScript. I have used 4 radiobutton in each row of Gridview.

**I Tried...**
**[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp2od.png**

```
<script>
            function GetCheckedRows() {
                var radio1 = null;
                var radio2 = null;
                var radio3 = null;
                var radio4 = null;
                $("#GridView1 tr").each(function () {
                    radio1 = $(this).find(".RadioButton1");
                    if (radio1.is(':checked')) {
                        radio2.checked = false;
                        radio3.checked = false;
                        radio4.checked = false;
                    }
                });
            }
        </script>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**javascript Code**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

$(document).on('click','.radio-class',function(){
  $this = $(this);
  // uncheck all other radio inputs except this one
  $('.radio-class').not($this).prop('checked', false);
});
```

**Radio Button**

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" GroupName="radio-class" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Give each row of radio buttons a different name

```
<div class="row">
  <input type="radio" name="rowA" /> Label A
  <input type="radio" name="rowA" /> Label B
  <input type="radio" name="rowA" /> Label C
  <input type="radio" name="rowA" /> Label D     
</div>
<div class="row">
  <input type="radio" name="rowB" /> Label A
  <input type="radio" name="rowB" /> Label B
  <input type="radio" name="rowB" /> Label C
  <input type="radio" name="rowB" /> Label D     
</div>
```

Comment: No No I want JavaScript code, There are 4 Radio button in the Gridview Each row. I want to get that if anyone is checked then uncheck another 3 of that row using Javascript.

Comment: I not looked, but you could try dropping in a radio button list control. it only allows one, and if it works - then you don't need any code.

Comment: @VivekRajSingh, I don't really get where you're going here. It's default HTML behaviour that when you check a radio button, all other radio buttons with the same name are unchecked. You don't need JavaScript for that